# Deleted wildcard 3 days ago still subdomains being resolved to other ip address

Tags: a-record, cpanel

I setup A record with wild card entry as I wanted to use some feature of my other website but I delete it for some reason. Now its been 3 days it still points to my other website. Is it cache issue if yes then how to reset it.
What's the actual way to deal with it

Example:

*.myonewebiste.com ----  |-----------       TTL    ------------ |        A ------------      | ------------       x.x.x.x ip of other website

after deleting I made a subdomain

now that I try to access it I am getting other site

I have tried

- adding some other A record manually

when i ping my wildcard it shows the IP of my other site
Totally its been a week I am stuck on this

I have checked subdomains, redirects for another duplicate entry that might point to my other site but nothing was there.

Comment: When asking about DNS issues, please give us the domain names you're having trouble with. That way we can query them ourselves to discover problems.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: `ping` is a utility intended for (basic) testing of connectivity, not for DNS/resolving issues. Debug DNS with `nslookup` or `dig`  (where with caching issues you can look for a decreasing TTL) and don't overlook any overrides that you may have added to your ``hosts` file..